# Add Content to webpage using only CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the task to display additional content on a webpage where the only thing I can access/modify is the css. 
How could I do it? (It will not be enough to add some plaintext or image with `xyz:after {content: 'bla';}` )
I know the underlaying page has jQuery included, but I can not access the html part which comes out of some sort of CMS. 
Are there any known tricks?

Comment: CSS is for **styling**. It should not be used for actual content.

Comment: You can not do it only with CSS. You can either use javascript or a server side language

Comment: First, there is no way to do, what you want to do, with only CSS. Second, CSS is not the place to do something like this. So: *Nope*.

Answer (score -1):

No, this will be impossible, the most you will be able to do is use `content`.
the full documentation on that can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content) though

Comment: OP has specifically stated that using `content` is not an option.

Comment: @Paulie_D And the answerer specifically stated it's impossible without it.